# comparing two arrays in php

Tags: php, arrays

I use this code :

```
 $new = array(
     "123" => "a",
     "456" => "b"
 );

 $old = array(
     "123" => "a",
     "456" => "b"
 );
```

then the `$new` array become like this:

```
 $new = array(
     "456" => "b",
     "123" => "c",
     "789" => "e"
 );
```

as you see the count of `$new` array increased and the order of elements changed and the value at key `123` also changed. I need to compare the `$new` array against the `$old` array and catch only the change made on the value at key `123` without caring about the order and the count of elements. I tried:

```
 $result = array_diff( $new, $old );
 print_r( $result );
```

output :

```
 Array ( [123] => c [789] => e )
```

Comment: What do you do with old and new one, that leads to the other new one? What do you want to see in result?

Comment: `echo 'Old: '.$old["123"].', New: '.$new["123"];` ???

Comment: Still not clear... you want an output like `Array ([123]=>c)` ?

Comment: Im pretty sure he wants to make the solution work for any sort of key @HamzA. I dont know how efficient this would be, but you could always do a foreach loop with key, value from "old", and then compare the value with the value from "new" with key from old: foreach(old as key=>value): if(new[key] != value) -> do something with it.

Comment: i want to see in result :Array ( [123] => c );

Comment: @user1910534 how do you get such array in result from your first code example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

UPDATE. quite confusing. now I think we got it

```
$old = array(
    "123"    => "a",
    "456"    => "b"
);
$new = array(
    "456"    => "b",
    "123"    => "c", // catch this (element in old array that is changed)
    "789"    => "e"
);

$new2 = array();
foreach ($new as $key => $new_val)
{
    if (isset($old[$key])) // belongs to old array?
    {
        if ($old[$key] != $new_val) // has changed?
            $new2[$key] = $new[$key]; // catch it
    }
}

// output $new2:
array (
  123 => 'c',
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You first of all want to have those elements of `$new` that are changed compared to `$old` (see [`array_diff_assoc`](http://php.net/array_diff_assoc)):

```
$changed = array_diff_assoc($new, $old);
```

Of that result you want to have only those elements that have their key in `$old` (see [`array_intersect_key`](http://php.net/array_intersect_key)):

```
$result  = array_intersect_key($changed, $old);
```

And that's it. You can wrap that into each other if it helps:

```
array_intersect_key(array_diff_assoc($new, $old), $old);
```

Result is:

```
array(1) {
  [123] =>
  string(1) "c"
}
```

Full example ([Demo](http://eval.in/5681)):

```
$old = array(
    "123" => "a",
    "456" => "b"
);

$new = array(
    "456" => "b",
    "123" => "c", // catch only the change made on the value at key 123 
    "789" => "e"
);

$changed = array_diff_assoc($new, $old);
$result  = array_intersect_key($changed, $old);

var_dump($result);
```

Just a final note: There are many array functions in PHP. It's worth to go through the list and look what is fitting because most often you only need one or two of them to get things like these done.

Comment: No doubt, besides looks much more beauty, I agreed. But the first issue was understand the problem asked. You have worked over my solution that clearly shows what the user asked. And second, use just one `foreach` and 2 `conditionals` is much more efficient that use 2 `functions`. In any case I probably use your way in a further challenge... Peace.

Comment: Well, the issue was well outlined in the question with the example data IMHO, anyway, I copied from your answer the arrays so I didn't need to type them, true. For the efficiency part, you should metric this (or the OP should do, this will differ by the size of the arrays a bit, I generally tend to use built-in array functions as they are fast, but foreach is fast, too. However you could spare the `if`s in your answer if you really want speed.

Comment: @hakre I would disagree regarding outline of the question.

Comment: @Eugene: Yes, it depends on how one understands it, that can greatly differ, sure. Not saying that you must have understood it clearly or something. You did some great work anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You use this code for your requirements

```
 <?php
    function key_compare_func($key1, $key2)
    {
        if ($key1 == $key2)
            return 0;
        else if ($key1 > $key2)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;
    }

    $array1 = array('blue'  => 1, 'red'  => 2, 'green'  => 3, 'purple' => 4);
    $array2 = array('green' => 5, 'blue' => 6, 'yellow' => 7, 'cyan'   => 8);

    var_dump(array_intersect_ukey($array1, $array2, 'key_compare_func'));
    ?>
```