# How to tell if array contains another array

Tags: php, arrays

Well this has been a headache.

I have two arrays;

```
$array_1 = Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => 'john'
            [age] => 30
        )

[1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => 'Amma'
            [age] => 28
        )

[2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => 'Francis'
            [age] => 29
        )

)
```

And another array

```
array_2 = = Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => 'Amma'
            )

    )
```

How can I tell that the id and name of `$array_2` are the same as the id and name of `$array_1[1`] and return `$array_1[1]['age']`?

Thanks

Comment: Can array_2 have many values in it?

Comment: This looks like some sql data, maybe a join would be a good option?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach($array_1 as $id=>$arr)
{
    if($arr["id"]==$array_2[0]["id"] AND $arr["name"]==$array_2[0]["name"])
    {
        //Do your stuff here
    }
}
```

Comment: Never thought of that before, Thats a-lot simpler. That'll help me, thanks!

Comment: dont you think its exactly the same as my answer ? ;)

Comment: You are awesome. Sorry for the delay as I was in a traffic ;)

Answer (score 3):

Well you can do it in a straightforward loop. I am going to write a function that takes the FIRST element in $array_2 that matches something in $array_1 and returns the 'age':

```
function getField($array_1, $array_2, $field)
{
   foreach ($array_2 as $a2) {
      foreach ($array_1 as $a1) {
         $match = true;
         foreach ($a2 as $k => $v) {
            if (!isset($a1[$k]) || $a1[$k] != $a2[$k]) {
              $match = false;
              break;
            }
         }
         if ($match) {
            return $a1[$field];
         }
      }
   }
   return null;
}
```

Comment: Bad idea to use `or`, it has a lower precedence than `!=`. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php. Means you have to use `||`. Or wait, do you mean it? ;)

Comment: Hey, I just wonder, did you actually read that?!? Haha, I made a mistake, `||` or `or` both have a lower precedence than `!=`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_diff()](https://www.php.net/array_diff).

In my opinion, using array_diff() is a more generic solution than simply comparing the specific keys.

Array_diff() returns a new array that represents all entries that exists in the first array and DO NOT exist in the second array.

Since your first array contains 3 keys and the seconds array contains 2 keys, when there's 2 matches, array_diff() will return an array containing the extra key (age).

```
foreach ($array_1 as $arr) {
   if (count(array_diff($arr, $array_2[1])) === 1) {//meaning 2 out of 3 were a match
      echo $arr['age'];//prints the age
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to find the age of somebody that has a known `id` and `name`.

This will work :

```
foreach ($array_1 as $val){
    if($val['id']==$array_2[0]['id'] && $val['name']==$array_1[0]['name']){
        $age = $val['age'];
    }
}
echo $age;
```

Comment: I wonder too. i didn't downvote. But your answer was correct.

Comment: If you don't trust me, i can downvote you, to show that your answer will be downvoted with "-1", (Only for testing of course) and then upvote again. Stackoverflow, should really consider showing who downvotes..

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into this.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_diff.asp

And

[comparing two arrays in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101557/comparing-two-arrays-in-php)

-Best